# First TestNG Code is not working

Tags: testng

**Selenium - TestNG Code is not working for me.**

```
package firsttestngpackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
```

**Define the testng class**

```
public class FirstTestNGFile {
public String baseURL = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();      
@Test
```

**Define the method**

```
public void verifyHomePageTitle() {
    driver.get(baseURL);
    String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
    String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
    driver.quit();              
}
}
```

**I am facing the following error while using testng **

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class firsttestngpackage.FirstTestNGFile
at    org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:31)
at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:410)
at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:323)
at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:126)
```

Comment: can you add full stack trace?

Comment: Could you share the whole FirstTestNGFile, or at least its constructor?

Comment: Hi juherr, if you are online I can share my screen with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try instantiating the driver in `@BeforeSuite` as -

```
public class FirstTestNGFile {
    public String baseURL = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
    public WebDriver driver;      

    @BeforeSuite
    public void SetBrowser(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyHomePageTitle() {
        driver.get(baseURL);
        ...
        driver.quit();              
    }
}
```

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user2\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (2)//chromedriver.exe");

Comment: I added this line in @BeforeSuite